# Catching Exit signal from Cherrypy server

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have an application which is served via Cherrypy. I want to catch the exit signal from Cherrypy server in case of server restarts/failures so I can perform some db cleanups.

I am aware of a subscribe/unsubscribe methods to achieve this but am not sure about it. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

Sad no one properly answered it in two years. And the cherrypy documentation is terrible. Here it is, for posterity, so others can avoid the trouble...

Assuming your custom quit function (to clean DBs, etc) is `my_quit_func`....

```
import cherrypy
from cherrypy.process.plugins import SignalHandler

signalhandler = SignalHandler(cherrypy.engine)
signalhandler.handlers['SIGTERM'] = my_quit_func
signalhandler.handlers['SIGHUP'] = my_quit_func
signalhandler.handlers['SIGQUIT'] = my_quit_func
signalhandler.handlers['SIGINT'] = my_quit_func
signalhandler.subscribe()
```

....then, **after** this block, start the main cherrypy thread using `cherrypy.quickstart` or whatever's your preference.